# nodejs catch finish, close, end events

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Folks,
  I am trying to write an express middleware which will catch finish events, and when a client has received the data and closed the connection.

In the following , only `finish` is working.   How do i get the events for clients receiving the data, and closing the socket.

```
function middleW(req, rsp, next){

  rsp.on('finish', function foo() {
    console.log ('FINISH');
  });

  rsp.on('end', function foo() {
    console.log ('END');
  });

  rsp.on('close', function foo() {
    console.log ('CLOSE');
  });

  return next();
}
```

Comment: When the connection is closed, the `finish` event is triggered, on receiving data you probably want `on('data', ...`

Comment: [HTTP `ServerResponse`s](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse), as [Writable streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable), don't emit an `'end'` event and their [`'close'` event](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_close_1) is conditional.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski That would make a good answer, I think.